# How to simulate a controlled, steady flow of water, and then disrupt it with object collisions to get some "gentle" turbulence?

Tags: particles, shaders, physics, fluid-simulation

I essentially want to recreate the same thing this program does, but in blender:  https://github.com/blackoffee/Shizuku

It doesn't need to be physically accurate, realtime or even 3D (shader editor magic would be great too). All I need is some detailed animations of turbulence in water in a gradient map type of look - pretty much exactly this: [image: reference screenshot]

I've tried particle simulations and mantaflow fluid simulations - neither give me the desired results. The main problem is that fluid and particle simulations, to my knowledge and testing, can't create a steady stream of water with no turbulence in it (apart from the colliders I'll put in there). The sims always create some sort of turbulence due to the inflow, or the collisions with the domain object. I'd essentially need a "slice" of a river that moves at a constant speed with no turbulence other than from the intentionally placed colliders (some cubes in the middle of the scene)

Any kind of help would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use “geometry“ instead of “inflow“ to fill a tub or something instantly with a block of water?

Comment: are these obstacles moving in the "river" or are they static?

Comment: @Blunder they can be static, but the river should moving at a slow and constant pace